# Weakest assumption for $\lim \sup x_n \in \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

What is the weakest assumption to be satisfied so that $\lim \sup x_n \in \mathbb R$. The same question for $\lim \inf x_n$.

Note that $\mathbb R$ does not include $\pm \infty$.

Should $x_n$ necessarily be bounded from above and below, or a weaker assumption will do?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was being silly. The correct condition is that $\lim \sup$ is finite iff $x_n$ is bounded from above and has a subsequence that's bounded from below.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks, I agree, if you bother to make an answer out of this, it will be accepted.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan BTW, can we claim that bounded from above and existence of a sub-sequence bounded from below not only sufficient but a necessary condition for a finite limsup?

Comment: Yes, that's what "iff" means.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan sorry missed "iff".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct condition is that $\limsup x_n$ is finite iff $x_n$ is bounded from above and has a subsequence that's bounded from below.